# Как через cmd перекомпилировать проекты sln в папках

Tags: c#

У меня есть .sln файл от софта. Как сделать чтобы софт через время к примеру через каждые 2 секунды, сам запускал exe от .sln для каждого проекта, чтобы мне не открывать .sln файл и не нажимать на кнопку Start и потом снова закрывать скомпилированный exe от .sln ??????

Comment: ВОПРОС ПОНЯТЕН ???

Comment: Честно? нет. Заголовок об одном, спрашиваете другое, в тексте вопроса третье. И не зачем кричать капсом. Вы лучше задачу опишите, чего хотите в результате? может вы не стой стороны к ней подходите

Comment: Хорошо, объясню по-другому. К примеру есть софт, написанный на c#. Когда я софт запустил, то в папке от софта появился exe файл то есть моя прога. Но я поменял "кое-что" в Program.cs и теперь чтобы то что я поменял имела силу, надо открывать .sln файл от проги запускать его, и ток тогда изменение будут в силе. Вопрос: как сделать это программно чтобы я только указал папку, и пусть комп сам ищет все файлы .sln в папках - подпапках. И запускает exe от этих найденных файлов, не открывая сам .sln файл(если можно пусть не открывает).

Comment: И соответственно новый exe который запустил комп от .sln файла, становится на замен тому exe который был до нового

Comment: Вам в любом случае нужно перекомпилировать проект. Это можно сделать из командной строки, в принципе. Без компиляции новый exe не появится.

Comment: Да-да, мне надо просто чтобы изменения были в силе и новый exe а остальное не надо

Comment: т.е. нужна автоматическая сборка и запуск проекта. Думаю стоит скорректировать вопрос, а то как-то долго до этой мысли добирались.

Comment: ну типо того, просто чтобы изменения были в силе, надо перекомпилировать файлы во всех папках (sln) но как это сделать через cmd ?

Answer (score 5):

Если на машине установлена Студия, проще всего в cmd-файле написать

```
"PATH TO VISUAL STUDIO\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" /build Release solution.sln
```

`PATH TO VISUAL STUDIO` — это путь к каталогу Visual Studio, выглядит обычно как `C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0` или что-то наподобие.

`solution.sln` — файл с .sln, он у вас должен быть.

---

Если у вас на машине *нет* Visual Studio, вам нужно хотя бы установить нужный фреймворк .NET (он бесплатный). У вас появится каталог с нужной версией фреймворка, натравите на solution msbuild.exe. Это выглядит как-то так (пути, разумеется, придётся подправить):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release path\to\solution.sln
```

---

Если вам нужно построить *несколько* .sln, проще наверное написать скрипт на powershell:

```
gci -r ТУТ_ВАШ_КАТАЛОГ *.sln | foreach { & C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release $_.FullName }
```

Comment: а если у меня папка с sln файлами на раб столе ?

Comment: @May_be: ... то укажите полный путь к .sln-файлу.

Comment: У меня папка на раб столе, и в этой папке тоже папки, и в этих папках находятся sln файлы, ток как сделать чтобы на все шло ?

Comment: у меня есть Студия

Comment: просто надо " 
У меня папка на раб столе, и в этой папке тоже папки, и в этих папках находятся sln файлы, ток как сделать чтобы на все шло ? " <-- это сделать


а как - я не знаю

Comment: @May_be: Ну, вам нужно найти все .sln-файлы, это отдельная задача, по идее

Comment: @May_be: Про студию/msbuild для будущих поколений :)

Comment: Мне правда очень надо

Comment: `for /r %i in (*.sln) do @echo %i` выведет все .sln в папке, включая вложенные папки. замените @echo на команду компиляции

Comment: for /r %i in (*.sln) do /build Release %i

Так?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting там еще много чего есть

Comment: @May_be нет, всю команду целиком, ну кроме sln файла и пути к нему. Любую из тепридложенных

Comment: то есть вместо @echo надо написан путь к папке где лежат .sln файлы?

Comment: for /r %i in (*.sln) do C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\test %i
и он выдал is not recognized там чете

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35534/discussion-between-may-be-and-rdorn).

Comment: @May_be: Дополнил ответ. Вариант у rdorn тоже хороший.

Answer (score 4):

**В дополнение к ответу @VladD**

Создайте .BAT файл в папке, где лежат нужные проекты и впишите в него строку:

```
for /r %i in (*.sln) do C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release "%i"
```

Данный цикл выполнит команду для всех найденных файлов в папке, включая вложенные, из которой был запущен. Естественно предварительно убедитесь что в команде указана правильная версия фреймворка и рабочая папка командной строки. или воспользуйтесь командой для студии.

**UPD**
Для удобного запуска, лучшее решение на мой взгляд, в настройках компилируемых проектов, руками прописать путь для Release и/или Debug версии в отдельную общую папку, и в ней разместить Bat-файл с таким же циклом на запуск найденных exe-файлов. После этого можно собрать общий bat-файл, запускающий последовательно компиляцию и запуск.