# Как скомпилировать ASP.Net Core проект из командной строки?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cmd, компиляция, asp.net-core

Есть проект ASP.Net Core и нужно через cmd команду его скомпилировать.Без Visual Studio.

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос - раз. Непонятна задача - два. Предлагаю дать ссылку на [csc.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe) и закрыть вопрос с формулировкой "слишком общий".

Comment: @"A K" Есть проект ASP.Net Core и нужно через cmd команду его скомпилировать.Без Visual Studio. Вроде чёткая задача- не расплывчатая. Csc компилирует cs файл, а я проект хочу целый

Comment: посмотрите тут для начала: https://stackoverflow.com/a/858205/5752652 В принципе, mvc проектам нужно ещё делать отдельный шаг для паблиша проекта, но думаю, для начала вам достаточно будет. Задача... мммм... видите ли, я просто хотел поинтересоваться, почему в век когда космические корабли бороздят просторы большого театра и компиляцию делают на сборочных серверах (teamcity) вам понадобилось делать самостоятельно сборку проекта?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490818/198316, формулировка в том вопросе дурная, но в обоих ответах есть нужное вам консольное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если именно ASP.NET Core, то

```
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

Comment: Ай, как красиво!

Answer (score 0):

Если же нужно именно скомпилировать (обычно когда так пишут предполагают сборку приложения), то:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet publish
```

или:

```
dotnet build
```