# Сделать Builder exe

Tags: c#

Имеется проект visual studio на C#, хочу сделать билдер, чтобы вводить некоторые данные, которые нужно изменить в коде и скомпилировать программу в exe файл. В интернете прочел много статей, но все они поверхностные, не описывают важные моменты. Знаю, что исходный код нужно вставить в txt файл и в нем менять нужные значения, но если код состоит из десятков классов, помещать в txt по порядку каждый класс начиная от programm.cs ? 
Буд рад любым ответам по данной теме

Comment: Поясните другими словами, что это означает: `чтобы вводить некоторые данные, которые нужно изменить в коде и скомпилировать программу в exe файл` ?

Comment: @MBo , вводишь данные в форму, например Admin, и в исходном коде содержание string Login меняется на Admin. Обычный билдер

Comment: Я просто не знаю, что такое билдер, и пока не вижу причин исходный код менять.

Comment: @MBo , причины есть, например не таскать с собой VS, чтобы редактировать проект и заново компилировать его. Запустил билдер, задал нужные параметры и скомпилировал exe для работы.

Comment: В чем проблема вынести эти данные в файл настроек?

Comment: 1) Вам не нужна студия чтобы просто скомпилировать проект. Для компиляции нужен только компилятор. Это утилита с интерфейсом командной строки. Не знаю как сейчас, но раньше компилятор шел вместе с фреймворком 2) Чтобы изменить переменную в памяти вам надо просто изменить переменную в памяти. Если вы это изменение хотите сохранить между запусками программы - используйте файл настроек. 3) Скорее всего тут никто (включая меня) не понял что в вашем понимании представляет собой билдер

Comment: 1) Студия - это только редактор кода + полезные рюшечки для разработки. Компилятор был и остается отдельным приложением, которое поставляется в составе .NET Framework, при этом имеет больше возможностей чем использует студия. 2) Для сборки проекта ( *.csproj) или решения ( *.sln) нужен MSBuild, который также поставляется в составе фреймворка и прекрасно работает без студии. 3) Вынесите ваши переменные в файл настроек или добавьте интерфейс для ввода значений при запуске приложения.

Comment: в ответах к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490818/198316) есть необходимые консольные команды